# Find nested element in query

Tags: jquery

I need to find an DropDownList with class  addressControlCountry. How?

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server"  CssClass="addressControlCountry" />
</div>
```

This doesn't work

```
$('#myDiv .addressControlCountry')
```

Comment: Where is the asp tag? shouldn't it be #myDiv?

Comment: You're asking a question about client side script but showing your server side code, would be much more useful if you posted the html that is generated when you visit the page.

Comment: why don't you check the generated html source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#myDiv').find('.addressControlCountry');
```

Answer (score 3):

What you already have should work, in theory. However, you could try one of the following:

```
$('#myDiv').children('.addressControlCountry')
$('#myDiv > .addressControlCountry')
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this

```
$('#myDiv > .addressControlCountry')
```

Comment: What difference would it make for it to work, if the other `ancestor descendants` didn't work. If the element was the direct child of `myDiv`, obviously it should have worked already, like it is.

Comment: Basically `$('#myDiv .addressControlCountry')` will search for an element having `id="myDiv"` and `class="addressControlCountry"` which is not the case. So we have to define that is should look to its descendants for provided class name.

Comment: Wrong! `$('#myDiv.addressControlCountry')` will search for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`$('#divLegalAddress).children()`

If divLegalAddress has more than one children you may use .eq()-function to pick the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You can scope by the outer div and then select the inner dropdown element as given below

$('.addressControlCountry','#myDiv')